# PostgreSQL how to?

Tags: php, postgresql

Хочу использовать базы данных за рамками LAMP, из серверных языков владею только PHP, очень привык к MySQL (mysqli ext), в полном распоряжении - Linux. Прошу поделиться мануляром как правильно установить pgsql, настроить, добавить пользователя, и через какое место с ней общаться, из среды php и консоли.

Comment: Поиск в интернете к адекватным результатам не привёл, просьба в гугл не посылать.

Comment: [Тут](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/installation.html) [есть](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/runtime-config.html) [ответы](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/client-authentication.html) на [все](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/reference-client.html) [ваши](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-psql.html) [вопросы](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pgsql.php).

Comment: @Timophey Lanevich, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 5):

<small>Вопросы по установке/развёртыванию это скорее на РутКод</small>

**1. Подключение репозитория**

Рекомендую последнюю ветку (9.2). Она [быстрее, выше, сильнее...](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.2)

Для  счастливых пользователей squeeze выполняем то что [тут](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt) написано

Для не менее счастливых пользователей убунты в стандартных репозиториях нет последней ветки, поэтому берём в `ppa` на launchpad:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:pitti/postgresql 
apt-get update
```

**2. Установка**

Если вы всё правильно сделали на предыдущих шагах, тогда всё получится:

```
apt-get install postgresql-9.2
```

**3. Настройка**

По умолчанию доступ к БД запрещён отовсюду, кроме локалхоста (самого сервера). Если вы хотите работать с сервером по сети, придётся выполнить некоторые настройки.

Во первых, прописать в `postgresql.conf` какие адреса слушать. Если все, то так:

```
listen_addresses='*'
```

если не все, то так:

```
listen_addresses='192.168.92.19'
```

Во вторых, соответствующим образом подредактировать `pg_hba.conf`

```
host all all all md5
```

(более подробная информация про этот файл [тут](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html), тут или [тут](http://wiki.dieg.info/doku.php/pg_hba.conf). Внимательно прочитайте про `auth-method` (`trust/md5/ident/...`))

Также необходимо установить пароль главному пользователю postresql. Для этого входите в psql и выполняете команду

```
alter user postgres with password 'newpassword'
```

Про добавление пользователей, баз данных и т.д. прочитайте [тут](http://guruadmin.ru/page/15-practical-postgresql-database-administration-commands).

**4. Использование**

Как [писал Erik Wurzer](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) ([перевод](http://habrahabr.ru/post/137664/)),

> PHP Data Objects (PDO) provide methods for prepared statements and working with objects that will make you far more productive!

Строка подключения будет выглядеть следующим образом: `"pgsql:dbname=some_database;user=dbusername;password=strongandsecretpassword;host=192.168.92.19"`

Comment: ничего себе развёрнутый ответ! +1.

Comment: Спасибо большое, она таки поднялась, в консоль попал. Буду курить МАНы.
А для общения из скрипта, наверно, напишу что-то своё, т.к. сейчас пользуюсь классом [отсюда][1], и буду уже своими руками собирать что-то похожее.

  [1]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/119294/